# How do I change a td element background on click and hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to change the background of a `td` element in a table when hovered, and also when clicked.

My code is follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="language" content="english">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<title>Table Highlighting</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('table').on('mouseover', 'tr', function(){
        $(this).css({
            'background-color': '#DBE9FF'
        });
    }).on('mouseout', 'tr', function(){
        $(this).css({
            'background-color': '#FFFFFF'
        });
    }).on('click', 'td', function(){
        $(this).parent().children().css({
            'background-color': '#FFFFFF'
        });

        $(this).css({
            'background-color': '#7DAFFF'
        });
    });
});
</script>
<style>
table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td
{
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Row 1 Col 1
        </td>
        <td>
        Row 1 Col 2
        </td>
        <td>
        Row 1 Col 3
        </td>
        <td>
        Row 1 Col 4
        </td>
        <td>
        Row 1 Col 5
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

It is working well, in that, when I click the `td` the background gets changed, but the hover is applied for `tr` and I need only for the `td` background to change on hover and click for the specific `td`, not other `td` tags.

Comment: have try to change tr for td in your script ?

Comment: Why exactly do you need javascript for a simple `:hover` ?

Comment: Hi @GCyrillus ya, i have tried with td also., same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I modify the above answer slightly. Try handling things with a little more CSS. Use hover pseudo instant of using javascript / jquery and if you can help it use a class to add style to your td.

CSS

```
tr td:hover
{
    background-color: #DBE9FF;
}

.active
{
  background-color: #7DAFFF;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
    $('table').on('click', 'td', function(){

        // Remove all active class from all td 
        $(this).parent().children().removeClass('active');

        // Add active class to current td target 
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fpYdt/3/)

Comment: Much better than hardcoding styles into javascript. Just add a comment to a 3rd line so he will know it allows only one td in the whole tr to have background changed (like radio button)

Answer (score 1):

It should be like 'tr td',

```
$('table').on('mouseover', 'tr td', function(){
        $(this).css({
            'background-color': '#DBE9FF'
        });
    }).on('mouseout', 'tr td', function(){
        $(this).css({
            'background-color': '#FFFFFF'
        });
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fpYdt/2/)

Comment: @jothikannan, as my understanding, i think you had only tr bg issue, do you mean to say when clicked on td, the color should be #7DAFFF and should not get changed on mouseout?

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind event on `table tr td` --

```
$(function(){
    $('table tr td').click(function(){
      $(this).css('background-color','#DBBBBF');    
    })

    $('table tr td').mouseout(function () {
      $(this).css('background-color','#FFFFFF');    
    });

    $('table tr td').mouseover(function () {
      $(this).css('background-color','#DBE9FF');    
    });       
});
```

[Try This](http://jsfiddle.net/c6H2c/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Only css is needed:

```
td:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Or javascript:

```
<td onmouseover="this.style.background-color = 'red';">
```

And .. how you can hover AND click an element at the same time? O.O